# Elementary vowel equations

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, english

## Challenge

Solve the following equations by converting to standard form (see below):

- `** eeeeee = aeeeeiiiouu`
- `** eeeeee = aeeeoouuu`
- `-/ eeeo = i`
- `*- eeooo = eeee`
- `/ aeiou = aeeioouu`
- `/+/ eiiiiii = eo`

## Brief Overview

This is essentially a cross between a math puzzle and a word puzzle.  I'll explain how this works by going backwards from a solution.

1. Start with an elementary equation:
    `1+1*2=3`
2. In English, this can be written:
    `one+one*two=three`
3. Remove all consonants:
    `oe+oe*o=ee`
   (Note: `aeiou` are the only vowels wrt this puzzle)
4. Move vowels to the end of each side of the `=` and sort:
    `+* eeooo = ee`

Again, you're going the *other* way; you are given form `4.` above, and expected to find form `1.` (or `2.`).

That is, the answer to: `+* eeooo = ee`

is: `1+1*2=3`

## Details

Rules followed by the puzzle format:

- Multiplication (`*`) and division (`/`) collectively are performed left to right.
  For example, `9*4/6*2` → `36/6*2` → `6*2` → `12`.
- Addition (`+`) and subtraction (`-`) are then performed left to right in a similar manner.
- All operands are positive integers.
- All intermediate results are also positive integers.
  For example, `2/4*2` will never appear in a solution because `2/4` is performed first, and this is not a positive integer.
  Likewise, `3-4+5` will not appear because `3-4` is not a positive integer.
- Numbers are in formal American English form.
  Briefly, don't use the article "a" or the conjunction "and" in number names; `101` is spelled `one hundred one`.
- Per the rules of this puzzle, answers that commute into each other (to form the same operator set) are considered equivalent.
  For example, if `j*k+l*m` works for some `j` `k` `l` `m`, `l*m+k*j` is considered the same answer.
- Notwithstanding the above equivalence principle, the solution to all challenge problems is unique.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1.

> 70*12*7=5880

3.

> 70-20/2=60

4.

> 42*2-7=77

5.

> 50000/20=2500

6.

> 96/6+36/6=22

Comment: I think 3 might be wrong. The question has three e's on the left while yours has four.  +1 for the others though.

Comment: @hexomino You're right, I miscounted. Fixed it.

Comment: Vowel counts don't match for one of your answers.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like 2 is still open?

> 10 * 17 * 20 = 3400